# Como cambiar el tipo de fecha en php?

Tags: php

¿Como cambiar una fecha que es `29/11/2019` a formato de **PHP** para ser exportado a **Mysql**?

Es decir `29/11/2019` > `2019-11-29`, `strtotime` cambia el formato pero no me ayuda con los separadores de `/` a `-`

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a SO en español. Edita la pregunta, e indica en texto el código que has intentado realizar. 
Así será mas fácil ayudarte, y evitarás que te cierren la pregunta por baja calidad.

Comment: un strtotime y un str_replace podría funcionarte

Comment: str_replace resolvio mi duda muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 5):

Lo ideal sería que hicieses uso de la clase [Datetime](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) ya que te va a permitir mucha más facilidad para manejar la fecha.

Los métodos usados serían [createFromFormat](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) y [format](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php).

El uso es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "29/11/2019");

echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

La salida sería:

```
2019-11-29
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la función de php `str_replace()` para cambiar los / por -. Luego de tener la fecha formateada podemos pasarla a timestamp con `strtotime()` y desde ahí en adelante puedes jugar como más te guste con el formato de salida.

> Recuerda configurar la zona horaria del servidor cuando trabajes con fechas, del contrario podrías tener algunos desfaces horarios.

Te dejo una función con lo mencionado anteriormente.

```
$date = "29/11/2019";

echo convert($date) . "<br />";
echo convert($date, "d-m-Y") . "<br />";
echo convert($date, "d-m-Y H:i:s");

function convert ($date, $output_format = "Y-m-d"){
  $date = str_replace("/", "-", $date);
  $timestamp = strtotime($date);
  $converted = date($output_format, $timestamp);
  return $converted;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes probar haciendo lo siguiente:

```
$date = "29/11/2019";
$date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
```